# How do I convert my Card to an NSSet?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to add a new `Card` to a `Deck` of cards, but am running into an issue when trying to save my card to the deck's `cards`.  How do I convert it to an `NSSet`?

```
func saveQA(question: String, answer: String) {
    let currentDeckName = deckName
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Card", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let newQA = Card(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    newQA.question = question
    newQA.answer = answer
    currentDeckName!.cards = newQA

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        userCards.append(newQA)
    }
    catch {
        let saveError = error as NSError
        print(saveError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you're trying to assign a `Card` to a property that is expecting an `NSSet`.  A card is not a set (although it could be an object in a set).

```
currentDeckName!.cards = newQA
```

**Taking advantage of type safety**

Since you are coding in Swift, the first thing you should do is use Swift types such as `Set` instead of `NSSet`. In your `Deck+CoreDataProperties.swift`, change your relationship from `NSSet?` to a typed set of cards.

```
@NSManaged var cards: Set<Card>
```

This not only tells Swift that `cards` is a Set, but also specifies that the objects in the set will be `Card`s.

You always want to declare specific types for relationships to benefit from the language's type safety.  This allows the compiler to prevent you from ever adding anything other than a `Card` to the deck's set of cards.

**Adding a card to the deck**

You could use the usual `Set` methods such as `insert` to insert a card into a deck's set.

```
currentDeckName.cards.insert(newQA)
```

However, a much easier way is to use the reverse relationship on the card itself.  In other words, tell the new card that it belongs to this deck:

```
newQA.deck = currentDeckName
```

That will automatically add the card to the deck's set of cards.

It's a bit less code, and less is generally better to read and understand.

Speaking of readability, you may want to consider renaming `currentDeckName` to `currentDeck` since that object is a `Deck`, not the name of a deck.

Comment: Just checked my sqlite file to see if everything stored correctly and it looks like it did. Thank you again @petah , you made my night better and much less frustrating as i learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For converting your object to `MutableSet` please verify with following step.

1) Select your `model object` 
2) select your parent `entity` 
3) Select `Relationship` which is `one To many`
4) now check following image `property` is `one To many` or not.

[image]

Comment: It is to many. I should add that my Core data model is Deck ->> Card. Deck has the attribute name, and Card has attributes question and answer

Comment: please upload image of your core data model so i can help out more on it.